# How do I get the unique document ID for a document I just created using document automations?

Tags: clio-api

After I make an API call (via make.com) for a new document automation, Clio returns a id that is not the unique document ID that I need to then download the document I just created via automation.

The id that it gives me is not the unique ID for the document.  Is there a way to get the unique ID for the document that I just created so that I can download it?

API CALL:
   `[ { "url": "/api/v4/document_automations.json", "body": "{\n  \"data\": {\n    \"document_template\": {\n      \"id\": 6670100\n        },\n    \"filename\": \"BI LOR - injured testinger\",\n    \"formats\": [\n      \"pdf\"\n        ],\n    \"matter\": {\n      \"id\":1616088274\n    }\n  }\n}", "method": "POST", "headers": [ { "key": "Content-Type", "value": "application/json" } ] } ]`
Returns this:
`"body": { "data": { "id": 213276124, "etag": "\"cb655dc653bf9ac6a68f6d0d2c363349\""  }`

When I go to https://app.clio.com/api/v4/documents/213276124/download.json it doesn't download a document as it's not the unique document ID of the document created above.  How do I get the unique docuemnt ID for a document I just created via a document automation API call?

Thank you!

Comment: Clio response:
To resolve this, in the POST request you are able to add fields in the Query Parameters to be returned to you once the Document is created. The example below will return the IDs of the Automation, Document and the Document Template.
 
https://app.clio.com/api/v4/document_automations?fields=id,documents{id},document_template{id}
//But I still come up empty. I got the above response from Clio API support.  It's good information, but still when I get the response, the document ID is empty.